# Can I play Dragons - Rise of Berk on the same account from an Apple device and an Android device?

Tags: ios, android, dragons-rise-of-berk

I have a *Dragons - Rise of Berk* account, logged with Facebook, which I play via iPad. Can I play from either the iPad or another Android device? (actually PC with Droid4x)

Of course I don't mean playing concurrently from both devices, but rather alternating between them.

Ludia states in the [FAQ](https://support.ludia.com/support/faq/show/46#1099) that switching to another device, *if* the account is connected to Facebook, should not present any issues, but that doesn't clear my doubts about consistently playing with the same account from different devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked Ludia support, and they answered the following:

> Hello,
>
> Sure, if you play the game through Facebook, all of your data is
> stored on the server and is accessible through any compatible device.
> All you have to do is install your game and sign in with your Facebook
> account to continue playing.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> (name)
>
> Ludia Support

Answer (score 1):

As long as the same account is used, the data will be synced where ever you play. You can try [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) or [Droid4X](http://www.droid4x.com/)  Android emulators to play Dragons - Rise of Berk on PC

Comment: If you're linking to your own site, we require you to disclose your affiliation to the site.  Otherwise, it would be classified as spam.  While I'm not sure how useful this would be, I have replaced the links with the official sites, not yours.